# Нужно создать функцию (аргумент строка из 6 цифр) и вывести вид билета по его значению, если первые 3 символа = 3 последним - счастливы и т..д

Tags: python-3.x

```
def ticket_type(items):
   for item in items[:]:
      if sum(item[0:3]) == sum(item[4:]):
            print('Lucky ticket')
      elif sum(item[0:3]) == sum(item[4:]-1):
            print('drunk ticket')
items = '122134'
ticket_type(items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sum` не поддерживает строку.
2. Срез говорит "взять **с** первого числа **до** второго. Нумерация с 0.

Выходит нужно преобразовать срез в числа и взять правильный срез во втором случае:

```
def ticket_type(item):
  if type(item) is str and len(item) == 6:
    if sum(int(n) for n in item[0:3] if n.isdigit()) == sum(int(n) for n in item[3:] if n.isdigit()):
      print('Lucky ticket')
    else:
      print('drunk ticket')

ticket_type('122134') # drunk ticket
ticket_type('122221') # Lucky ticket
```

https://repl.it/EW6V/0